# Formating text with CSS in a DNN skin

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, skin

I have this html in a web page.

```
<span>Inovative International Industry<span/>
```

I'm trying to make it look like this

```
 Innovative
 International 
 Industry
```

But by using `<span>Inovative <br/> International <br/> Industry<span/>`, I get

```
 Innovative

 International 

 Industry
```

Any ideas? I'm a C#/Java developer, HTML, CSS, design, etc, are not my strongest assets.
Cheers
Rui Martins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try
`<div>Innovative</div><div>International</div><div>Industry</div>`

or on your span you could try

`<span style="line-height:normal">`